# NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath method returns true but no directory was created

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

In my app, I want to create a directory and put some txt files in it. Here is my code to create the directory

```
-(BOOL)createFolderInDocuments:(NSString *)folderName
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];
    
    BOOL success = YES;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
    
    if(error){
        UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                     alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error"
                                     message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Create folder: %@", error]
                                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        
        UIAlertAction* okButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){}];
        [alert addAction:okButton];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Created folder with name %@", folderName);
    }
    return success;
}
```

After I ran the method, I got this message in console

```
2021-11-01 15:16:23.786293+0800 my-app[887:167944] Created folder with name 2021-11-01T15-16-23
```

which means method `createDirectoryAtPath` returned `true`.

From my experience by using this repo https://github.com/Varvrar/ios_logger, after I ran the method, I should get a folder with my app name in the Finder location as shown below.
[image]

But I got nothing here. Actually, I couldn't find the directory anywhere on my iPhone. So I guess it was not created at all.

Could anyone tell me how to create the directory correctly? Thanks!

Comment: "But I got nothing here"  Where is 'here,' exactly?  You are only allowed to create a folder inside the sandbox folder assigned to your app.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the exact location of it on iPhone. I can find it by following the section "See the iOS and iPadOS apps that can share files with your Mac" in this tutorial https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210598

Comment: Use `NSLog` to print the dataPath guy.

Comment: @El Tomato I did it, the result is "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/73E4106A-B108-4CEA-B7E3-F829CF861577/Documents/2021-11-01T16-23-56"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. The directory was indeed created, it was just not showing in Finder when the iPhone connected to Mac.

In order to make it show in Finder, add this entitlement in the xcode project info.plist
[image]